# Send POST request using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm trying to perform a POST request to a remote REST API using `NSURLSession`. The idea is to make a request with two parameters: `deviceId` and `textContent`.

The problem is that those parameters are not recognized by the server. The server part works correctly because I've sent a POST using POSTMAN for Google Chrome and it worked perfectly.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
NSString *deviceID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
NSString *textContent = @"New note";
NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"deviceId=%@&textContent=%@", deviceID, textContent];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_to_manage_post_requests"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPBody = [noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // The server answers with an error because it doesn't receive the params
}];
[postDataTask resume];
```

I've tried the same procedure with a `NSURLSessionUploadTask`:

```
// ...
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_to_manage_post_requests"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:[noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // The server answers with an error because it doesn't receive the params
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tangentially, if you just use a `NSURLSessionUploadTask`, it posts raw data to your server. Which you can still work with -- for instance, via `file_get_contents('php://input') in PHP` -- but you have to include other data in the headers.

Comment: I had a different issue but the tip-off regarding `Content-Type` was all that I needed to figure things out. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason this has stopped working for me all of a sudden on latest ios8. It worked like a champ for a year then all of a sudden I am getting malformed requests at the server and I am not sure what to change in how I compose the request. I could not replicate the problem users were having with XCode simulator, then I upgraded to XCode 6.3.1 and kablam I am screwed - just killing me. Cannot figure why my server is so unhappy with the requests.

Comment: I am following your example and have to send multi fields with image. I am sending PNG image format. Running into an issue, please help me resolve it. I have a django based server and it throws an error for image. "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Comment: [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n", @"image_file"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:pageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: a curl command like below work "curl -i -F "page_index=0" -F "p=1" -F "image_file=@./FullSizeRender.png" http://gmm.com:5000/p/images/
HTTP/1.1"

Comment: The "solution" in the question should be added as an answer :)

Comment: is it necessary to add additional headers ?

Comment: Appending all strings and only converting to data when the full string is composed will also work, while making it a bit more readable :)

Comment: Please do not put answers to your question, if you have one post as an answer rather than putting it there. Please refer to this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155204/318827) on Meta

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You could try using a NSDictionary for the params. The following will send the parameters correctly to a JSON server.

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[JSON SERVER"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                     @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                     nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

(I'm trying to sort a CSRF authenticity issue with the above - but it does send the params in the NSDictionary).

Comment: It worked perfecty! Thank you @greentor! Any idea how can I upload a image along with the "plain" data?

Comment: I've found the solution for my first problem (no need to mess with  `NSJSONSerialization`) and I've added the code to post images along with other parameters. I have updated the original post. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: thank you so much greentor i was finding solution from long back. your post helped me to resolve my all the issues with Post call to rest service from ios 7

Comment: @sendoa , if you know how to how to upload a image along with thr "plain" data? i need the solution urgent. many thanks in advance

Comment: @GaganJoshi read the "Sending images along with other parameters" section of my initial post :-)

Comment: How to attach image/file data with this solution?

Comment: I added NSURLSessionConfiguration but my api is calling twice. Can you please give me suggestion?

Answer (score 21):

## Motivation

Sometimes I have been getting some errors when you want to pass **`httpBody`** serialized to `Data` from `Dictionary`, which in most cases is due to the wrong encoding or malformed data due to non [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding) conforming objects in the `Dictionary`.

## Solution

Depending on your requirements one easy solution would be to create a `String` instead of `Dictionary` and convert it to `Data`. You have the code samples below written in Objective-C and Swift 3.0.

### Objective-C

```objectivec
// Create a URLSession with the default configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

// Setup the request to the URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF-8 Encoding
NSString *postParams = @"api_key=APIKEY&email=example@example.com&password=password";
NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Add the data to the request
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

// Create dataTask
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // Handle your response here
}];

// Fire the request
[dataTask resume];
```

### Swift

```swift
// Create the URLSession with the default configuration
let defaultSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultSessionConfiguration)

// Setup the request to the URL
let url = URL(string: "yourURL")
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)  // Note: This is a demo, that's why I use implicitly unwrapped optional

// Convert POST string parameters to data using UTF-8 Encoding
let postParams = "api_key=APIKEY&email=example@example.com&password=password"
let postData = postParams.data(using: .utf8)

// Add the data to the request
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = postData

// Create dataTask
let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    // Handle your response here
}

// Fire the request
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks. Very clean answer. Why is that that request should be mutable?  What could possibly mutate? Or is it because you are constantly appending ( like an Array or Dictionary maybe) the `url`, then `method` then `body` so it must be mutable? And if that is the case then where would ever need to use `NSURLRequest`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use https://github.com/mxcl/OMGHTTPURLRQ

```
id config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:someID];
id session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:someObject delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue new]];

OMGMultipartFormData *multipartFormData = [OMGMultipartFormData new];
[multipartFormData addFile:data1 parameterName:@"file1" filename:@"myimage1.png" contentType:@"image/png"];

NSURLRequest *rq = [OMGHTTPURLRQ POST:url:multipartFormData];

id path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.NSData"];
[rq.HTTPBody writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

[[session uploadTaskWithRequest:rq fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] resume];
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not sure I understand the complaint about this not being "clear coding". If you would have ever had to create your own multipart form data with NSURLSession you would know that this saves you an insane amount of coding. In the above example by @mxcl it only takes two lines to create the request. To implement this by yourself it would take you something like 12 lines, at least.

Comment: I've just realized how they've manage to build the multipart request. They grab the file to upload and save it in some other file with the body of the request in it too. Then they can use uploadTaskWithRequest: fromFile:. Since you cannot use any of the NSData methods to upload in the background, they've modified the actual file. Great idea. the backgroundSessionConfiguration does not allow for a custom body. Whatever you put in the request object's body is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 2.0 solution is here:**

```
 let urlStr = “http://url_to_manage_post_requests” 
 let url = NSURL(string: urlStr) 
 let request: NSMutableURLRequest =
 NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!) request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 request.setValue(“application/json” forHTTPHeaderField:”Content-Type”)
 request.timeoutInterval = 60.0 
 //additional headers
 request.setValue(“deviceIDValue”, forHTTPHeaderField:”DeviceId”)

 let bodyStr = “string or data to add to body of request” 
 let bodyData = bodyStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) 
 request.HTTPBody = bodyData

 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
             (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

             if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("responseCode \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
             }

            if error != nil {

                 // You can handle error response here
                 print("\(error)")
             }else {
                  //Converting response to collection formate (array or dictionary)
                 do{
                     let jsonResult: AnyObject = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:
 NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers))

                     //success code
                 }catch{
                     //failure code
                 }
             }
         }

   task.resume()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Swift, the [Just](https://github.com/justhttp/Just) library does this for you. Example from it's readme file:

```
//  talk to registration end point
Just.post(
    "http://justiceleauge.org/member/register",
    data: ["username": "barryallen", "password":"ReverseF1ashSucks"],
    files: ["profile_photo": .URL(fileURLWithPath:"flash.jpeg", nil)]
) { (r)
    if (r.ok) { /* success! */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Teja Kumar Bethina's code changed for Swift 3:

```
    let urlStr = "http://url_to_manage_post_requests"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)

    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    request.timeoutInterval = 60.0

    //additional headers
    request.setValue("deviceIDValue", forHTTPHeaderField:"DeviceId")

    let bodyStr = "string or data to add to body of request"
    let bodyData = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.httpBody = bodyData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("responseCode \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }

        if error != nil {

            // You can handle error response here
            print("\(error)")
        } else {
            //Converting response to collection formate (array or dictionary)
            do {
                let jsonResult = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:
                    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers))

                //success code
            } catch {
                //failure code
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    use like this.....

    Create file

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`    
    #import "SharedManager.h"
    #import "Constant.h"
    #import "UserDetails.h"

    @interface APISession : NSURLSession<NSURLSessionDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
    +(void)postRequetsWithParam:(NSMutableDictionary* )objDic withAPIName:(NSString* 
    )strAPIURL completionHandler:(void (^)(id result, BOOL status))completionHandler;
    @end

****************.m*************************
    #import "APISession.h"
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @implementation APISession

    +(void)postRequetsWithParam:(NSMutableDictionary *)objDic withAPIName:(NSString 
    *)strAPIURL completionHandler:(void (^)(id, BOOL))completionHandler
    {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strAPIURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSError *err = nil;

    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSString *strJsonFormat = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"API URL: %@ \t  Api Request Parameter ::::::::::::::%@",url,strJsonFormat);
    //    NSLog(@"Request data===%@",objDic);
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    //  NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionTask *task=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
                            {
                                if (error==nil) {
                                    NSDictionary *dicData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];\
                                    NSLog(@"Response Data=============%@",dicData);
                                    if([[dicData valueForKey:@"tokenExpired"]integerValue] == 1)
                                    {

                                        NSLog(@"hello");
                                        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Access Token Expire." forKey:@"message"];
                                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserLogOut" object:self userInfo:dict];
                                    }
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        completionHandler(dicData,(error == nil));
                                    });
                                    NSLog(@"%@",dicData);
                                }
                                else{
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        completionHandler(error.localizedDescription,NO);
                                    });
                                }
                            }];
    //    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [task resume];
    //    });
    }
    @end

    *****************************in .your view controller***********
    #import "file"
    txtEmail.text = [txtEmail.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    {
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
            [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

            NSMutableDictionary *objLoginDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [objLoginDic setValue:txtEmail.text forKey:@"email"];
            [objLoginDic setValue:@0            forKey:kDeviceType];
            [objLoginDic setValue:txtPassword.text forKey:kPassword];
            [objLoginDic setValue:@"376545432"  forKey:kDeviceTokan];
            [objLoginDic setValue:@""           forKey:kcountryId];
            [objLoginDic setValue:@""           forKey:kfbAccessToken];
            [objLoginDic setValue:@0            forKey:kloginType];

            [APISession postRequetsWithParam:objLoginDic withAPIName:KLOGIN_URL completionHandler:^(id result, BOOL status) {

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                NSInteger statusResponse=[[result valueForKey:kStatus] integerValue];
                NSString *strMessage=[result valueForKey:KMessage];
                if (status) {
                    if (statusResponse == 1)
                {
                        UserDetails *objLoginUserDetail=[[UserDetails alloc] 
                        initWithObject:[result valueForKey:@"userDetails"]];
                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                        setObject:@(objLoginUserDetail.userId) forKey:@"user_id"];
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                        [self clearTextfeilds];
                        HomeScreen *obj=[Kiran_Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
                    }
                    else{
                        [strMessage showAsAlert:self];
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
**********use model class for represnt data*************

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constant.h"
    #import <objc/runtime.h>


    @interface UserDetails : NSObject
    @property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *emailId,
    *deviceToken,
    *countryId,
    *fbAccessToken,
    *accessToken,
    *countryName,
    *isProfileSetup,
    *profilePic,
    *firstName,
    *lastName,
    *password;

    @property (assign) NSInteger userId,deviceType,loginType;

    -(id)initWithObject :(NSDictionary *)dicUserData;
    -(void)saveLoginUserDetail;
    +(UserDetails *)getLoginUserDetail;
    -(UserDetails *)getEmptyModel;
    - (NSArray *)allPropertyNames;
    -(void)printDescription;
       -(NSMutableDictionary *)getDictionary;

    @end

    ******************model.m*************

    #import "UserDetails.h"
    #import "SharedManager.h"

    @implementation UserDetails



      -(id)initWithObject :(NSDictionary *)dicUserData
       {
       self = [[UserDetails alloc] init];
       if (self)
       {
           @try {
               [self setFirstName:([dicUserData valueForKey:@"firstName"] != [NSNull null])? 
               [dicUserData valueForKey:@"firstName"]:@""];


               [self setUserId:([dicUserData valueForKey:kUserId] != [NSNull null])? 
               [[dicUserData valueForKey:kUserId] integerValue]:0];


               }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@",exception.description);
        }
        @finally {
        }
    }
    return self;
}

    -(UserDetails *)getEmptyModel{
    [self setFirstName:@""];
    [self setLastName:@""];



    [self setDeviceType:0];


    return self;
       }

     -  (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //    Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:_firstName forKey:kFirstName];


    [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:_deviceType] forKey:kDeviceType];

    }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        _firstName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kEmailId];

        _deviceType= [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:kDeviceType] integerValue];

    }
    return self;
    }
    - (NSArray *)allPropertyNames
    {
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    NSMutableArray *rv = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [rv addObject:name];
    }

    free(properties);

    return rv; 
    } 

    -(void)printDescription{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for(NSString *key in [self allPropertyNames])
    {
        [dic setValue:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
    NSLog(@"\n========================= User Detail ==============================\n");
    NSLog(@"%@",[dic description]);
    NSLog(@"\n=============================================================\n");
    }
    -(NSMutableDictionary *)getDictionary{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for(NSString *key in [self allPropertyNames])
    {
        [dic setValue:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
    return dic;
    }
    #pragma mark
    #pragma mark - Save and get User details
    -(void)saveLoginUserDetail{
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [Shared_UserDefault setObject:encodedObject forKey:kUserDefault_SavedUserDetail];
    [Shared_UserDefault synchronize];
    }
      +(UserDetails *)getLoginUserDetail{
      NSData *encodedObject = [Shared_UserDefault objectForKey:kUserDefault_SavedUserDetail];
    UserDetails *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
    return object;
   }
    @end


     ************************usefull code while add data into model and get data********

                   NSLog(@"Response %@",result);
                  NSString *strMessg = [result objectForKey:kMessage];
                 NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result 
                objectForKey:kStatus]];

            if([status isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {
                arryBankList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                NSMutableArray *arrEvents=[result valueForKey:kbankList];
                ShareOBJ.isDefaultBank = [result valueForKey:kisDefaultBank];
                if ([arrEvents count]>0)
                {

                for (NSMutableArray *dic in arrEvents)
                    {
                        BankList *objBankListDetail =[[BankList alloc]initWithObject:[dic 
                         mutableCopy]];
                        [arryBankList addObject:objBankListDetail];
                    }
           //display data using model...
           BankList *objBankListing  =[arryBankList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_