# Minimal POST example for NSURLSession

Tags: post, nsurlsession

I must be missing something basic because I am unable to get any NSURLSession examples using POST to work at all.  I have my server set up to print out (to a file that I tail) all the received POST parameters and nothing I put in the POST body shows up.  I've tried the solutions from [Send POST request using NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession) as well as online tutorials such as [the Ray Wenderlich Cookbook for using NSURLSession](http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession).

Here, for example, is the code almost directly from the [Stackoverflow thread, mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession), with only the URL and the post arguments changed:

```
-(void)postTest {
    NSString *textContent = @"XXXXX";
    NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=%@", textContent];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                               @"a"       : @"YYYYY"
                                               };
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[MY URL with PHP script]"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPBody = [noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    outputLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

The PHP script shows the "XXXXX" parameter was properly received - but it's not part of the POST body; rather, it is part of the URL itself.  The only parameter in the POST body is the "YYYYY" parameter but it doesn't show up at all.

The Ray Wenderlich example didn't work either: nothing showed up for the PHP script.

```
-(void)testPost {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[MY URL with PHP script]"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"a": @"YYYYY"};
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask =
          [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                            fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                            }];
        [uploadTask resume];
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm not setting somewhere?  I hadn't expected the shift to NSURLSession would have such subtle boobytraps and I'm wondering if it's something silly I'm doing wrong or missing.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:completionHandler:) about the request parameter on uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:completionHandler:

> An NSURLRequest object that provides the URL, cache policy, request
>   type, and so on. The body stream and body data in this request object
>   are ignored.