# How can i pass dictionary parameter to url using post method

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am tired to do this..but i can't get respose..

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"access_name", @"about us", nil];
    NSDictionary *finalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict, @"cmscontent", nil];

    NSString * post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",finalDict];

    NSData *postdata= [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postdata length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];


    NSString *str=@"http://my url...";
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postdata];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *returnstring=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict12=[returnstring JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",dict12);
```

and my json dictionary parameter is..

```
{
  "cmscontent": 
    {
          "access_name": "about us"
    }
}
```

so please tell me how can i get response??
thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the URL? And you want to pass dictionary in jSON string? Have you tried converting Dictionary to JSON string

Comment: in this code passing all dictionary as parameter..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request using NSURLSession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession)

Comment: how is that supposed to work with `NSString *str=@"http://my url...";`

Comment: I think you should be using `application/json` as `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the forHTTPHeaderField content type vale

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

i hope this will resolve..
Thanks