# Post an array of geoPoint as parameters, but the data from api response is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api, afnetworking

There is an `api` that I need to post the `geoPoint`, then get data, which works fine on `Postman`. Like shown in the image,
[this api works fine on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znodE.jpg)

In my code, I use the following way to call `api`

```
NSArray *geoPoint = @[@114.33f, @22.44f];

NSDictionary *geoPointDic = @ {@"geoPoint" : geoPoint};
NSDictionary *inData = @{
                         @"action" : @"getNearbyEventList",
                         @"data" : geoPointDic};

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"data" : inData};

NSLog(@"geoPoint is %@", geoPoint);
NSLog(@"upcoming events parameters %@", parameters);

[_manager POST:GetURL parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSDictionary *  responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject is %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"responseObject - data is %@", responseObject[@"data"]);

    NSArray *eventsArray = responseObject[@"data"];
```

But the output is

when `NSLog` parameters:

```
events parameters {
    data =     {
        action = getNearbyEventList;
        data =         {
            geoPoint =             (
                "114.33",
                "22.44"
            );
        };
    };
}
```

[the api response looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxsOr.jpg)

I guess my parameters might be in wrong format, so I tried the following way, but no one works

```
//NSArray *geoPoint = [[NSArray alloc] init];

//NSArray *geoPoint = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"114", @"22", nil];

//NSMutableArray *geoPoint = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//[geoPoint addObject:@114];

//[geoPoint addObject:@22];

//NSArray *geoPoint = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"114", @"22", nil];

//NSString *geoPoint = @"[114.33,22.44]";
```

So, could anyone tell me how to get the data like shown in the `Postman`, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 NSData *dataBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
 NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

Object json same is data you send to server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried. But there will be "Request failed: internal server error (500)", if I don't send NSDictionary but use NSString as parameters.  > <

Comment: I think it useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099448/send-post-request-using-nsurlsession